# Problem installing a programing using Discover

Tags: software-installation

Using Kubuntu 18.04. I tried to install the program "Palapeli" using Discover. When I tried to run from the launcher or from the "Launch" button in Discover, I received an error saying the application wasn't found. I uninstalled and re-installed and had the same problem. I uninstalled and then installed the package using Synaptic and it works fine.

Is there someone I should advise about Discover?

Comment: Discover in Kubuntu 18.04 has some rough edges. I don't use it. I prefer the command line. I could install and launch Palapeli from Discover itself in Kubuntu 19.04 (in a VM). I'm not sure the developers would backport improvements to Discover for 18.04 because 18.04 has some limitations related to the version of qt it can use.